# Symbols for Quantifiers Other Than $\forall$ and $\exists$

Tags: notation, quantifiers

The symbols $\forall$ and $\exists$ denote "for all" and "there exists" quantifiers. In some papers, I saw the (not so common) quantifiers $Я$ and $\exists^+$, denoting "for a randomly chosen element of" and "for most elements in", respectively.

Are there other symbols for quantifiers?

I'm specially interested in quantifiers for:

- for all but finitely many elements of...
- for infinitely many elements of...

---

**Edit:** After seeing some of the comments, I found the [list of logic symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols) and the [table of mathematical symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_mathematical_symbols), which I could be useful for others.

Comment: $\exists !$: There exist exactly one

Comment: $\nexists$: Does not exist

Comment: I've sometimes seen $\forall\forall$ used to mean "for all but finitely many elements", but I don't know if this is a common convention or not.

Comment: Some people seem to use $\nabla$ for "for most", in the sense of a fixed ultrafilter.

Comment: @Chris: For ${\mathcal U}$ an ultrafilter, I have seen ${\mathcal U}$ itself used as a quantifier, so ${\mathcal U}x\phi(x)$ means that the set of $x$ such that $\phi(x)$ is in ${\mathcal U}$. This is convenient in a context where one may be using several different ultrafilters or where the role of a specific ${\mathcal U}$ wants to be emphasized.

Comment: @Andres: that notation could subsume the "for all but finitely many" case once you introduce a fixed symbol for the Fréchet filter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most commonly used symbols to express "for all but finitely many" and "there are infinitely many" are $\forall^\infty$ and $\exists^\infty$, respectively.

Comment: Other common quantifiers are $\forall^*$ and $\exists^*$, used in the context of a Polish space (such as ${\mathbb R}$). The first means "for all but a meager set of points", the second "there is a non-meager set of points".

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: For sequences (and sort of for nets—but uglier since cofinality comes into the picture) I've also seen the terms "eventually" and "frequently" for "for all but finitely many" and "for infinitely many" respectively. E.g. "$n^2 \gt 2n$ eventually" ($\exists N : n \geq N \implies n^2 \gt 2n$) and "$\sin n \lt 0$ frequently" ($\forall N \exists n : n \geq N \land \sin n \lt 0$)

Comment: An extension of this would be models of languages with added quantifiers that express "there exist uncountably many" or "there exist $\kappa$ many, for $\kappa > \aleph_{1}$".  The first case I've seen explored when the language is our standard first-order logic, but I've not seen treatments of the latter.

Answer (score 5):

Not quite a symbol per se, but of course there is "a.e." ("almost everywhere"):  "for all but a set of measure zero".  Probabilists call it "a.s." ("almost surely").  They are also in the habit of writing "a.a." ("almost all"): "for all but finitely many" and "i.o." ("infinitely often"): "for infinitely many".

In potential theory, one also sees "q.e." ("quasi-everywhere"): "for all but a set of capacity zero".

Answer (score 2):

Jaśkowski used $\Pi$ for quantifying over propositions.  So he would write

$$\Pi a . \Pi b. a \to b \to a$$

It is useful for formalizing things like "does double negation elimination imply LEM", which you have to write as

$$(\Pi a. \lnot \lnot a \to a) \to (b \lor \lnot b)$$

IIRC he used $\Sigma$ for existential quantification over propositions.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow it is missing that $∃_∞$ and $∀_∞$ both are first order definable when for example the domain is the natural numbers. We then have:

**there are infinitely many**
$∃_∞x A(x) \Leftrightarrow ∀y ∃x (x \geq y \wedge A(x))$

**for all but finitely many**
$∀_∞x A(x) \Leftrightarrow ∃y ∀x (x \geq y \Rightarrow A(x))$

Not all exotic quantifiers are that simple, see for example:
Modal Quantifiers, Natasha Alechina - 1995
http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psznza/papers/Alechina:95d.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Have seen a symbol that looks somewhat like $\forall \!\!\!\! - $ or $ \large \vee \!\!\!\!\!\!\! = $ frequently used by my teachers for "for all but finitely many" (equivalently, "for all large enough" in the context of natural numbers). Ergo, used that frequently myself in class. Surprised to find that it is not as standard as I have always taken it to be.