# How to write “there exists an infinite number of”?

Tags: notation, predicate-logic

We all know that `∃` means “there exists” and `∃!` means “there exists exactly one”. Is there a similar notation for existence of an infinite number of examples?

Comment: $\exists^\infty x P(x)$

Comment: Most mathematicians don't use such notation. So be careful about using it.

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko Thanks! Searching the internet for `"exists infty"` actually turned up examples of it being used, and it has the benefit of being rather obvious.

Comment: Ok, I edited as follows to satisfy your condition !
$$$$
$$\exists A;\bigg( |A|\geq\aleph_0 \wedge \big(\forall x\in A:\phi(x)\big)\bigg)$$

Comment: @Simon I believe that $\exists^\infty$ is a rather standard abbreviation, just like $\exists x\in A, P(x)$ is standard for $\exists x(x\in A \& P(x))$. Of course, in a published paper one would usually remind the reader the meaning of this notation, before using it, if it is not considered standard.

Comment: Yes, but most of time explaining verbally is clearer from notation :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already suggested $\exists^\infty x P(x)$, let me try to collect some relevant links. I agree that perhaps this notation is not standard, but I have seen it often enough, and it seems a natural choice of notation to abbreviate the statement that there are infinitely many $x$ that satisfy property $P(x)$. 
It could be easily explained and agreed upon, at the beginning of a paper or an exposition, and then use it without danger of confusion.

A related MSE question (the most voted up answer by François G. Dorais suggests $\forall^\infty$ "for all but finitely many", and $\exists^\infty$ "there are infinitely many"). 
[Symbols for Quantifiers Other Than $\forall$ and $\exists$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21379/symbols-for-quantifiers-other-than-forall-and-exists)

A related MO question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74739/almost-all-quantifier (the discussion there is related to semantics and logic, rather than merely the notation).

Discussion at wikipedia (e.g. list things like $\exists^\mathrm{many}$, in the context of probability spaces,apart from formal logic discussion). 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_%28logic%29

Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, Generalized Quantifiers (does not specifically advocate the use of $\exists^\infty$ but the discussion is related): 
http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/generalized-quantifiers/

A paper by M.Weese, uses $Q_0$ for "there exist infinitely many"
http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2040997?uid=3739256&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21104634537081

I admit I didn't find as much as I wish online, to confirm that the notation $\exists^\infty$ is standard (and some of what I found was related specifically to logic, rather than to "everyday" mathematics), but I know I did not invent it, and I have seen it used in papers.